# Java.util.Date compare ">="

Tags: java, date

In `java.util.Date` the function `after()` == ">"

Is there a way to compare dates as ">=" ?

Answer (score 10):

How about using

```
!thisDate.before(thatDate)
```

to implement the ">=" function. Not hugely nice, I appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

What about "not before"?

> boolean result = !date.before(otherDate)

Also, [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) can save you a lot of time :)

Answer (score 1):

`Date` implements `Comparable`, so you can use the `compareTo` method:

```
if (date.compareTo(otherdate) >= 0) { ... }
```

Basically `compareTo` is the Java way for comparing objects with `>`, `<=` etc. and works in lots of circumstances. The `after` and `before` methods of `Date` probably exist only because they were introduced before `compareTo` was added.

Answer (score 0):

`if (!date.before(otherdate)` -  has the same effect as " not after or equal to"

Answer (score 0):

No ....Java does not support that...instead you can use

[`Date#equals()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`Date#after()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29)

I too also prefer [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)